# How to apply In with page in spring boot jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
Page<JobApplicationModel> findByUserIdAndIdIn(long userId, List<Long> ids, Pageable pageable);
```

The above code doesn't work with pagination but the lower code works fine. Can someone explain why and how I can make the above also work?

```
Page<JobApplicationModel> findByUserIdAndIdNotIn(long userId, List<Long> ids, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: @Andronicus nope just it gives the wrong page data. Is page size is 4 then it will give total element 4 in page even if I have 40 elements.